# Addon Properties for Material, Objects etc

Tags: add-on, properties

we are working on a Addon to import W3D files used in the old CnC, and Battle for Middle Earth games.
In order to import these files properly we have to add some custom properties to the object and material types etc. 
All of the script examples I found do not work.
Could someone pls post a working example on how to add a custom property and display it in the properties section of the objects material?
E.G. we will have to set an enum "surface type" for each material.

Thanks in advance
Tarcontar